# Tikz multiline node with center align

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, nodes

I have a problem with nodes in scheme. I need type a node where will be text "Banka melovskych filtru". Each word on a special line with center align.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the `align=center` option. See the manual for further text options.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=center] {Banka \\ melovskych \\ filtru};
\end{tikzpicture}
```